# Can't I have fixed-size arrays in arguments? fn a<T,N>(arr: & [T; N])

Tags: rust

In the code below:

```
fn a<T,N>(arr: & [T; N]) {
    
}
```

why do I get

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `N`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:22
  |
1 | fn a<T,N>(arr: & [T; N]) {
  |                      ^ not a value
```

?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8023f8d13b34369ec0453883630617ba

I know I can expect just `&[T]` but I guess that if I expect with a fixed size then it ues stronger typing and also no bound checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you: you declared `N` as a type parameter, but arrays expect a *value*. So you need to declare `N` as a value as shown in e.g. [the const generics announcement](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/26/const-generics-mvp-beta.html#what-are-const-generics). This means prefixing it with the `const` keyword and giving it a type:

```rust
fn a<T, const N: usize>(arr: &[T; N]) {
    
}
```